# CSV to XML conversion using MFL

Tags: oracle, transform, osb, oracle-service-bus

I have an CSV file like:

```
1234|abc|val1=12;val2=13;val3=14
1235|xyz|val1=15;val2=16;val3=18
```

I need to convert it into XML using mfl file.

This is my approach:

```
<StructFormat name='player' delimOptional='n' repeat='*'>

    <FieldFormat name='FieldID' type='String' delimRef='' delim='|' dataDelim='"' delimOptional='n' optional='n' codepage='UTF-8'/>

    <FieldFormat name='playerName' type='String' delimRef='' delim='|' dataDelim='"' delimOptional='n' optional='n' codepage='UTF-8'/>

    <StructFormat name='extraList' delim='|' delimOptional='n' optional='y'>

        <FieldFormat name='extra' type='String' delimRef='' delim='|' delimOptional='n' optional='y' codepage='UTF-8' repeat='*'/>

    </StructFormat>

</StructFormat>
```

I don't know how to implement unlimited amount of couples: `val1=12` assigned to each player.

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be generated by tool, check used wizard for

Group Occurrence -> Repeat Delimiter -> Select this option to indicate that the group will repeat until the specified delimiter is encountered.

as per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs70/diuser/fmtdef.htm - dated but still ok